# facing nulls for no reason in android studio

Tags: java, android

I am facing 2 nulls in my app when I try to use some buttons in it . I have checking and reviewing my codes for 3 days till now but I can not solve the null
logCat shows me that the

> null is at ".Question.getCorrectAnswer() /
> QuestionFragment.showCorrectAnswer(QuestionFragment.java:175) and
> QuestionActivity.onActivityResult(QuestionActivity.java:419)"
>
> and other button shows null at
> "AnswerSheetHelperAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() / at
> QuestionActivity.onActivityResult(QuestionActivity.java:436)"

But I'm sure that there are no nulls at all: I need help from expert people maybe they find something I cannot find cause I am a rookie for now.

This is my Question script:

```
public class ResultGridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ResultGridAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<CurrentQuestion> currentQuestionList;

    public ResultGridAdapter(Context context, List<CurrentQuestion> currentQuestionList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.currentQuestionList = currentQuestionList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_result_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {

        Drawable img;

        myViewHolder.btn_question.setText(new StringBuilder("Question").append(currentQuestionList.get(i)
                .getQuestionIndex() + 1));
        if (currentQuestionList.get(i).getType() == Common.ANSWER_TYPE.RIGHT_ANSWER) {
            myViewHolder.btn_question.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff99cc00"));
            img = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_check_white_24dp);
            myViewHolder.btn_question.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, img);
        } else if (currentQuestionList.get(i).getType() == Common.ANSWER_TYPE.WRONG_ANSWER) {
            myViewHolder.btn_question.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffcc0000"));
            img = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_clear_white_24dp);
            myViewHolder.btn_question.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, img);
        } else {
            img = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_error_outline_white_24dp);
            myViewHolder.btn_question.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, img);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return currentQuestionList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        Button btn_question;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            btn_question = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_question);
            btn_question.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context)
                            .sendBroadcast(new Intent(Common.KEY_BACK_FROM_RESULT).putExtra(Common.KEY_BACK_FROM_RESULT
                                    , currentQuestionList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getQuestionIndex()));
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

This is my QuestionFragment:

```
public class QuestionFragment extends Fragment implements IQuestion {

    TextView txt_question_text;
    CheckBox ckbA, ckbB, ckbC, ckbD;
    FrameLayout layout_image;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    Question question;

    int questionIndex = -1;


    public QuestionFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question, container, false);

        questionIndex = getArguments().getInt("index", -1);
        question = Common.questionList.get(questionIndex);

        if (question != null) {
            layout_image = (FrameLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_image);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
            if (question.isImageQuestion()) {
                ImageView img_question = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_question);
                Picasso.get().load(question.getQuestionImage()).into(img_question, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            } else
                layout_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            txt_question_text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_question_text);
            txt_question_text.setText(question.getQuestionText());

            ckbA = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ckbA);
            ckbA.setText(question.getAnswerA());
            ckbA.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean b) {
                    if (b)
                        Common.selected_values.add(ckbA.getText().toString());
                    else
                        Common.selected_values.remove(ckbA.getText().toString());

                }
            });

            ckbB = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ckbB);
            ckbB.setText(question.getAnswerB());
            ckbB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean b) {
                    if (b)
                        Common.selected_values.add(ckbB.getText().toString());
                    else
                        Common.selected_values.remove(ckbB.getText().toString());

                }
            });

            ckbC = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ckbC);
            ckbC.setText(question.getAnswerC());
            ckbC.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean b) {
                    if (b)
                        Common.selected_values.add(ckbC.getText().toString());
                    else
                        Common.selected_values.remove(ckbC.getText().toString());

                }
            });

            ckbD = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ckbD);
            ckbD.setText(question.getAnswerD());
            ckbD.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean b) {
                    if (b)
                        Common.selected_values.add(ckbD.getText().toString());
                    else
                        Common.selected_values.remove(ckbD.getText().toString());

                }
            });


        }
        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public CurrentQuestion getSelectedAnswer() {

        CurrentQuestion currentQuestion = new CurrentQuestion(questionIndex, Common.ANSWER_TYPE.NO_ANSWER);
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        if (Common.selected_values.size() > 1) {
            //for multi choices this will make it multi arrays for answer if it has multi value
            Object[] arrayAnswer = Common.selected_values.toArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayAnswer.length; i++)
                if (i < arrayAnswer.length - 1)
                    result.append(new StringBuilder(((String) arrayAnswer[i]).substring(0, 1)).append(","));
                else
                    result.append(new StringBuilder((String) arrayAnswer[i]).substring(0, 1));
        } else if (Common.selected_values.size() == 1) {
            Object[] arrayAnswer = Common.selected_values.toArray();
            result.append((String) arrayAnswer[0]).substring(0, 1);
        }

        if (question != null) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(result)) {
                if (result.toString().equals(question.getCorrectAnswer()))
                    currentQuestion.setType(Common.ANSWER_TYPE.RIGHT_ANSWER);
                else
                    currentQuestion.setType(Common.ANSWER_TYPE.WRONG_ANSWER);
            } else
                currentQuestion.setType(Common.ANSWER_TYPE.NO_ANSWER);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Cannot get Question", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            currentQuestion.setType(Common.ANSWER_TYPE.NO_ANSWER);
        }
        Common.selected_values.clear();
        return currentQuestion;
    }

    @Override
    public void showCorrectAnswer() {

        String[] correctAnswer = question.getCorrectAnswer().split(",");
        for (String answer : correctAnswer) {
            if (answer.equals("A")) {
                ckbA.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                ckbA.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            } else if (answer.equals("B")) {
                ckbB.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                ckbB.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            } else if (answer.equals("C")) {
                ckbC.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                ckbC.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            } else if (answer.equals("D")) {
                ckbD.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                ckbD.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void disapleAnswer() {

        ckbA.setEnabled(false);
        ckbB.setEnabled(false);
        ckbC.setEnabled(false);
        ckbD.setEnabled(false);


    }

    @Override
    public void resetQuestion() {

        ckbA.setEnabled(true);
        ckbB.setEnabled(true);
        ckbC.setEnabled(true);
        ckbD.setEnabled(true);

        ckbA.setChecked(false);
        ckbB.setChecked(false);
        ckbC.setChecked(false);
        ckbD.setChecked(false);

        ckbA.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        ckbA.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        ckbB.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        ckbB.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        ckbC.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        ckbC.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        ckbD.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        ckbD.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    }
}
```

This is my QuestionActivity:

```
public class QuestionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private static final int CODE_GET_RESULT = 9999;
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
int time_play = Common.TOTAL_TIME;
private static final String time_Format = "%02d:%02d:%02d";
boolean isAnswerModeView = false;


TextView txt_right_answer, txt_timer, txt_wrong_answer;

RecyclerView answer_sheet_view;
AnswerSheetAdapter answerSheetAdapter;
AnswerSheetHelperAdapter answerSheetHelperAdapter;


ViewPager viewPager;
TabLayout tabLayout;


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (Common.countDownTimer != null)
        Common.countDownTimer.cancel();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_question);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(Common.selectedCategory.getName());
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    //we need to import question from db
    takeQuestion();

    if (Common.questionList.size() > 0) {

        //to show timer and answer
        txt_right_answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_question_right);
        txt_timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_timer);

        txt_timer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txt_right_answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        txt_right_answer.setText(new StringBuilder(String.format("%d/%d", Common.right_answer_count, Common.questionList.size())));

        countTimer();


        //view
        answer_sheet_view = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.grid_answer);
        answer_sheet_view.setHasFixedSize(true);
        if (Common.questionList.size() > 5)
            answer_sheet_view.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, Common.questionList.size() / 2));
        answerSheetAdapter = new AnswerSheetAdapter(this, Common.answerSheetList);
        answer_sheet_view.setAdapter(answerSheetAdapter);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);

        genFragmentList();

        QuestionFragmentAdapter questionFragmentAdapter = new QuestionFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                this,
                Common.fragmentsList);
        viewPager.setAdapter(questionFragmentAdapter);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            int SCROLLING_RIGHT = 0;
            int SCROLLING_LEFT = 1;
            int SCROLLING_UNDETERMINED = 2;

            int currentScrollDirection = 2;

            private void setScrollingDirection(float positionOffset) {
                if ((1 - positionOffset) >= 0.5)
                    this.currentScrollDirection = SCROLLING_RIGHT;
                else if ((1 - positionOffset) <= 0.5)
                    this.currentScrollDirection = SCROLLING_LEFT;
            }

            private boolean isScrolledDirectionUndetermined() {
                return currentScrollDirection == SCROLLING_UNDETERMINED;
            }

            private boolean isScrollingRight() {
                return currentScrollDirection == SCROLLING_RIGHT;
            }

            private boolean isScrollingLeft() {
                return currentScrollDirection == SCROLLING_LEFT;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {
                if (isScrolledDirectionUndetermined())
                    setScrollingDirection(v);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int i) {
                QuestionFragment questionFragment;
                int position = 0;
                if (i > 0) {
                    if (isScrollingRight()) {
                        questionFragment = Common.fragmentsList.get(i - 1);
                        position = i - 1;
                    } else if (isScrollingLeft()) {
                        questionFragment = Common.fragmentsList.get(i + 1);
                        position = i + 1;
                    } else {
                        questionFragment = Common.fragmentsList.get(position);
                    }
                } else {
                    questionFragment = Common.fragmentsList.get(0);
                    position = 0;
                }
                CurrentQuestion question_state = questionFragment.getSelectedAnswer();
                Common.answerSheetList.set(position, question_state);
                answerSheetAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                countCorrectAnswer();

                txt_right_answer.setText(new StringBuilder(String.format("%d", Common.right_answer_count))
                        .append("/")
                        .append(String.format("%d", Common.questionList.size())).toString());
                txt_wrong_answer.setText(String.valueOf(Common.wrong_answer_count));

                if (question_state.getType() != Common.ANSWER_TYPE.NO_ANSWER) {
                    questionFragment.showCorrectAnswer();
                    questionFragment.disapleAnswer();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {
                if (i == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
                    this.currentScrollDirection = SCROLLING_UNDETERMINED;
            }
        });

    }
}

private void finishGame() {
    int position = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
    QuestionFragment questionFragment = Common.fragmentsList.get(position);
    CurrentQuestion question_state = questionFragment.getSelectedAnswer();
    Common.answerSheetList.set(position, question_state);
    answerSheetAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    countCorrectAnswer();

    txt_right_answer.setText(new StringBuilder(String.format("%d", Common.right_answer_count))
            .append("/")
            .append(String.format("%d", Common.questionList.size())).toString());
    txt_wrong_answer.setText(String.valueOf(Common.wrong_answer_count));

    if (question_state.getType() != Common.ANSWER_TYPE.NO_ANSWER) {
        questionFragment.showCorrectAnswer();
        questionFragment.disapleAnswer();
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
    Common.timer = Common.TOTAL_TIME - time_play;
    Common.no_answer_count = Common.questionList.size() - (Common.wrong_answer_count + Common.right_answer_count);
    Common.data_question = new StringBuilder(new Gson().toJson(Common.answerSheetList));

    startActivityForResult(intent, CODE_GET_RESULT);

}

private void countCorrectAnswer() {
    Common.right_answer_count = Common.wrong_answer_count = 0;
    for (CurrentQuestion item : Common.answerSheetList)
        if (item.getType() == Common.ANSWER_TYPE.RIGHT_ANSWER)
            Common.right_answer_count++;
        else if (item.getType() == Common.ANSWER_TYPE.WRONG_ANSWER)
            Common.wrong_answer_count++;
}

private void genFragmentList() {
    for (int i = 0; i < Common.questionList.size(); i++) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("index", i);
        QuestionFragment fragment = new QuestionFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        Common.fragmentsList.add(fragment);
    }
}


private void countTimer() {
    if (Common.countDownTimer == null) {
        Common.countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(Common.TOTAL_TIME, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                txt_timer.setText(String.format(time_Format,
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                //finish the game :]
                finishGame();
            }
        }.start();
    } else {
        Common.countDownTimer.cancel();
        Common.countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(Common.TOTAL_TIME, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                txt_timer.setText(String.format(time_Format,
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                //finish the game :]

            }
        }.start();
    }
}

private void takeQuestion() {
    Common.questionList = DBHelper.getInstance(this).getQuestionByCategory(Common.selectedCategory.getId());
    if (Common.questionList.size() == 0) {
        //this one in case category is empty
        new MaterialStyledDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Coming Soon !")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_sentiment_very_dissatisfied_black_24dp)
                .setDescription("The content is coming soon waite for " + Common.selectedCategory.getName() + " category ")
                .setPositiveText("ok")
                .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        finish();
                    }
                }).show();
    } else {

        if (Common.answerSheetList.size() > 0)
            Common.answerSheetList.clear();

        //gen answers from answersheet each question will has online 1 answer sheet content

        for (int i = 0; i < Common.questionList.size(); i++) {
            Common.answerSheetList.add(new CurrentQuestion(i, Common.ANSWER_TYPE.NO_ANSWER)); //no answer is default

        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_wrong_answer);
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) item.getActionView();
    txt_wrong_answer = (TextView) constraintLayout.findViewById(R.id.txt_wrong_answer);
    txt_wrong_answer.setText(String.valueOf(0));
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.question, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.menu_finish_game) {
        if (!isAnswerModeView) {
            new MaterialStyledDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Finish ?")
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_mood_black_24dp)
                    .setDescription("Do you really want to finish?")
                    .setNegativeText("NO")
                    .onNegative(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    .setPositiveText("YES")
                    .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            finishGame();
                        }
                    }).show();
        } else
            finishGame();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);


    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CODE_GET_RESULT) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String action = data.getStringExtra("action");
            if (action == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(action)) {
                int questionNum = data.getIntExtra(Common.KEY_BACK_FROM_RESULT, -1);
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(questionNum);

                isAnswerModeView = true;
                Common.countDownTimer.cancel();

                txt_wrong_answer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                txt_right_answer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                txt_timer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                if (action.equals("viewquizanswer")) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

                    isAnswerModeView = true;
                    Common.countDownTimer.cancel();


                    txt_wrong_answer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    txt_right_answer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    txt_timer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    for (int i = 0; i < Common.fragmentsList.size(); i++) {
                        Common.fragmentsList.get(i).showCorrectAnswer();
                        Common.fragmentsList.get(i).disapleAnswer();
                    }
                } else if (action.equals("doitagain")) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

                    isAnswerModeView = false;
                    countTimer();


                    txt_wrong_answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txt_right_answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txt_timer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    for (CurrentQuestion item : Common.answerSheetList)
                        item.setType(Common.ANSWER_TYPE.NO_ANSWER);
                    answerSheetAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    answerSheetHelperAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    for (int i = 0; i < Common.fragmentsList.size(); i++)
                        Common.fragmentsList.get(i).resetQuestion();

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use Debug mode and breakpoints ?

Comment: Include the entire logcat for both crashes.

Comment: Your errors seem to be related to 'Question' class, you should post it, or at least post something to understand its function and functions

Comment: @Bruno

yes i tried but i sends me to another line saying that it gives the null
and i tried to change it as recommended but still gets the same 2 nulls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never initializing `answerSheetHelperAdapter`, so it's `null`.  That's one of your problems.

It's impossible to tell why the other one is null without an actual stack trace and more code, but you're probably setting it to null in

```
question = Common.questionList.get(questionIndex);
```

See [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/) for more information on how to debug this.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.quiz.Model.Question.getCorrectAnswer()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.quiz.QuestionFragment.showCorrectAnswer(QuestionFragment.java:173)
        at com.example.quiz.QuestionActivity.onActivityResult(QuestionActivity.java:419)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7454)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.quiz.Adabter.AnswerSheetHelperAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.quiz.QuestionActivity.onActivityResult(QuestionActivity.java:436)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7454)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e-Bt95820oTL_MjypjohehLPbs0x1u-R

this link includes my whole project if anyone wants to help you can easily find all errors by running it cause i am a newbie so i cannot determine whole errors by myself 

thanks for help

Comment: For future reference:  People are not going to look in your Google drive.  Relevant code and stack traces should be included in the question itself, not in comments, or images, or links to an off-site repository, etc.  Requests for debugging assistance should *include* a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).